# How to seal interior aquaponic system?

Tags: water, drain, drainage

I'm working on a aquaponic aquarium system that is part of the home improvement and I can't find proper part that would help me instal the drainage from the plant pot.

I'm looking for some pvc pipe that has the thread at the end and is possible to screw with the seal touch so the water doesn't leak. I'm trying to avoid using weld option but if I won't find anything I will need to weld it somehow.

Please see the pic:
[image]

Comment: Swimming pools use these kinds of [fittings](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=pool+fittings&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=59395869205&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=5887555275247658965&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_5bkdm3lwec_e).  The inlet/return cover goes on the inside of the pool, and screws to the fitting outside of the pool, creating a tight seal.

Comment: If you are just trying to make your current PVC fittings work, you could probably use a ton of silicone caulk to create a fat gasket under the fitting.

Comment: @mbeckish, I'm worried about using silicone caulk as it may affect the quality of fish life. The swimming pools fitting is too short...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for bulkhead fitting (and PVC if you must), just about every hardware store has them.  There's plenty of examples of hacks using regular fittings as well.

Comment: bulkhead fitting is what I was looking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Aquarium grade Room Temperature Vulcanizing (rtv) silicone will not harm fish life - it's what holds nearly every glass aquarium made in the last 40 years or so together. If the aqaurium in your picture is glass, it's probably glued with silicone. Read the label on the tube. Somewhere in the fine print there will, or will not be a mention of *suitable for aquarium use.* If it's not there, don't use it. If it is, use it, paying attention to required cure times. Honestly, the PVC is more questionable than silicone; look up organotins.

Unless you really want to pay extra, the product will be sold as clear silicone caulk (it may or may not actually say RTV, but it is) and you just need to find the fine print in question on it.

Of course, if it's remotely like the picture you can also just  poke a hole in the SIDE of the pot at the proper level - anything "leaking" from there will "leak" into the aquarium.

Comment: this is true but I don't want to do it this way. Thanks for the suggestion though!